# How to remove last letters from column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I got the following dataframe

| Initial |
| --- |
| M.H.. |
| T.H. |

How  can i remove  the  .. from M.H.. to M.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with escape `.`:

```
df['Initial'] =  df['Initial'].str.replace(r'\.+', ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string indexing,

```
string[:-1]
```

In your case,

```
"M.H.."[:-1]
```